# EmberJS - Unable to get parameters from action

Tags: ember.js, parameters, action

I have problem in getting parameter values in action. If I try it in controller I am getting only null or undefined.

Here is my Template

```
<button  {{action  "select" this someParameter   target=controller on="doubleClick"}} >OK </button>
```

Here is my Controller

```
App.SampleController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    actions: {
        select: function(param1) { 
                alert("clicked"+param1);
            console.log(param1);
        },     
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this -

```
App.SampleController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
actions: {
    select: function(param1, param2) {
        alert("clicked "+param1 + param2);
        console.log(param1, param2);
    }
}
```

});

you should use `ObjectController`

And in the HTML -

```
<button  {{action  "select" this "someParameter"   target=controller on="doubleClick"}} >OK </button>
```

DEMO - [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ajey/jocr97w9/1/)

Comment: Thanks for your response, But still I am facing the same problem. Here I have attached my Fiddle please go through it.          http://jsfiddle.net/RaguNS/7fLff100/3/

Comment: You'r welcome. Please accept the answer if your problem is sovled.